# How to automate the event for clicking on the app menu button in android emulator using Appium?

Tags: c#, android, appium

I want to click on the app menu button on the android emulator device.[andoid emulator home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vRrh.png)

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;

    namespace AppTesting

{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
        [TestMethod]

        public void Scroll_Method()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

            cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "TestingMachine");
            cap.SetCapability("platformversion", "7.0");
            cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");

            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            driver.PressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.Keycode_MENU);

        }

    }

}
```

but when I run the code I get the following error

> Message: Test method AppTesting.UnitTest1.Scroll_Method threw
>   exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The
>   desired capabilities must include either an app, appPackage or
>   browserName

I am new to mobile automation testing, what I don't understand at this point is why I need to provide an app-package and app-activity even when I am clicking on the button that is present on the home screen. If it is necessary to provide than what is the *"app-package"* and *"app activity"* for clicking the menu button.

Note:
Also, help on how to scroll through the android native application menu. Thanks in advance. Solution to this single problem will be an answer to many other problems that I am facing right now. I am new to mobile automation testing using Appium with C# in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie you can try [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/).
They have the object spy feature which would be easier for you to identify the elements. 
And its possible to swipe the screen without providing the app-activity.

```
client.swipe(swipeDirection,offset,timeToSwipe);
```